# Why redirecting to stdout with dup2 works only if printf was called before redirecting

Tags: c, printf, stdout, dup2

I'm trying to write a program that connects to a server opened with `nc -v -l 1337` on another terminal, and redirects stdin, stdout, stderr to the socket.
Meaning, the other terminal will write to the socket, and my program will read it with `getchar()` and respond using `printf()`.

I came across something strange - everything works fine if I comment out the first use of printf (before `dup2(sockfd,1)`). If not, printing does nothing. What can cause this?

```c
int main() 
{ 
    int sockfd, connfd; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 

    // socket create and varification 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(1337); 

    connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    dup2(sockfd,0);
//---------------------------
//  printf("%s\n","hi" );
//---------------------------
    dup2(sockfd,1);
    dup2(sockfd,2);

    char buff[80]; 
    int n; 
    while(1){
        n = 0;
        while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n');
        buff[n-1] = 0;
        printf("message %s excepted\n",buff ); 
    }
    // close the socket 
    close(sockfd); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix:**

You  need to tell your program to flush `stdout` when writing to it:

```
    while(1){
        n = 0;
        while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n');
        buff[n-1] = 0;
        printf("message %s excepted\n",buff ); 

        /* ask the system to flush stdout */
        fflush(stdout);
    }
```

**Reason: (I'm just guessing)**

Not all FILE stream are buffered the same.

FILE stream connected to a terminal will be flushed when a `\n` is to be print.

FILE stream connected to a socket will be flushed when buffer is full.

By calling `printf("...\n");` before `dup2();`, you force the first behavior.

Comment: This explanation sounds very reasonable (Though it would be nice if I could find it documented somewhere :-), thanks, That's the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Your program is doing what is expected, `dup2(sockfd,0);` will close the standard input of your client program (that is, the text entered from your keyboard in the terminal where you launched your program), and use `sockfd` as your new standard input. Quoted from [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2):

> dup2() makes newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if necessary

To put this in evidence, try to launch your listening socket program this way :

- `cat | nc -v -l 1337` in terminal 1
- wrap your socket client program with `strace` (e.g. `strace a.out`) in terminal 2

The text typed in terminal 1 (where you launched the server listening on port 1337) will be sent over the socket, received in terminal 2 over `fd 0` (which is now a copy of `sockfd`), and sent back over the socket because of the redirection of standard output (fd 1) to `sockfd`.

You may want to comment out `dup2(sockfd,1);` if you'd rather not send the text back to the server but have it displayed to terminal 2 instead. Alternatively, you may want to comment out `dup2(sockfd,0);` to keep the standard input of your client program to your keyboard and send the text entered from terminal 2 over the socket.

Not sure that answers your question, but I think `strace` + `cat` will help you understand how you can manage the various files descriptors in place.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would say this could be a buffering issue. A common fix, as suggested is flushing the socket, otherwise try setting the buffer for stdout to 0 might fix this behaviour.

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```